# How to get unique products_sku with count in mysql query

Tags: mysql

How to get unique products_sku with count in mysql query

e.g :  `testrsp(4),TS234(2),152427(11)`

products_sku

```
testrsp
testrsp
testrsp
testrsp
TS234
TS234
152427
152427
152427
152427
152427
152427
152427
152427
152427
152RE
152RE
152RE
152RE
152RE
152427
152RE
2030C
18062007P
18062007P
18062007P
18062007P
18062007P
152427
509P
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using combination of count and group by like:

```
SELECT products_sku, COUNT(*)
FROM   mytable
GROUP BY products_sku
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple `group by` with a `count`

```
select products_sku, count(*) from `table` group by products_sku
```